# How to get desired output

Tags: prolog

I have written the following code in Prolog. It executes like this:

```
?- colors('c:/users/30698/desktop/a.txt', Answer).
Answer = 0.
```

How can i modify it to execute like this (I have to submit it to an automated system for evaluation and the first one won't pass):

```
?- colors('c:/users/30698/desktop/a.txt', Answer).
Answer = 0 ;
false.

colors(File, Answer):-
    read_input(File, N, K, C),
    min_len(C, N, K, M) -> Answer is M; Answer is 0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually prefer your implementation, but the one the system seems to be demanding is something like this:

```
colors(File, Answer) :-
   read_input(File, N, K, C),
   min_len(C, N, K, Answer).

colors(_, 0).
```

Your use of the conditional `->` is eliminating a choice point that the automated system seems to expect. Tsk-tsk to the automated system for being unnecessarily specific.

You could probably also just add the following nonce clause to get your current code accepted:

```
colors(_, _) :- fail.
```